# In there any difference between *<variable> and <variable>* in C?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, return-type, function-declaration

in the following function declaration

`my_struct* create(char *name);`

Is there any difference in the meaning of `*` in `my_struct*` and `*name`?

I understand that `char *name` means that we will pass a char pointer to the function `my_struct` called `name`. I also get that the function will return a pointer to (memory address of) something. What I don't understand is why `my_struct*` and not `*my_struct`?

Comment: it's not `*name` it's `char*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
my_struct * create(char *name);
```

the name of the function is `create`. The function has one parameter of the type `char *`, And the function has the return type `my_struct *`. That is it returns a pointer to an object of the type `my_struct`.

> Is there any difference in the meaning of * in my_struct* and *name

`my_struct` is a type specifier. So `my_struct *` is a pointer type. `name` is identifier that denotes the name of a parameter. The type of the parameter (identifier) `name` is `char *`.

Pay attention to that these declarations of the parameter are the same

```
char* name
char * name
char *name
```

that is the type of the parameter is `char *` and the name of the parameter is `name`.

In a function declaration that is not at the same time its definition names of parameters may be omitted.

So the above function declaration can be also written like

```
my_struct * create( char * );
```